# Modify apache 2 to use different Perl instance

Tags: apache-2.2, solaris, perl, cgi

I have 2 installed Perl on the OS, now my cgi script need to run the module on newly installed Perl, I've already set played the PERL5LIB, @INC to include the new instance but it doesn't work.

Any way to modify apache to look/use the new Perl instance?

Answer (score 0):

Can you start your cgi script with a she-bang, using the path of your desired perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

Comment: Adding the desired perl on header as you suggested works.

Comment: @lupin -- thanks.  If you are satisfied with the solution, could you mark my answer as accepted?